# Problems with defining UPLOADS constant

Tags: uploads

I have a custom Wordpress file-structure like

### web-root:

- content (folder)

  - uploads (folder)
  - plugins (folder)
  - themes (folder)
    ... and so on
- wordpress (folder)

  - wp-admin (folder)
  - wp-includes (folder)
    ... more folders
  - wp-blog-header.php
  - wp-load.php
  - wp-login.php
    ... and all other wp core files

.htaccess

index.php

### wp-config.php

In my `wp-config.php` I have to define the path to my custom uploads folder like this:

```
if (!defined('UPLOADS')) {
    define('UPLOADS', '../content/uploads');
}
```

More or less out of nothing (maybe I updated the wp core) when trying to upload an image I get the error message saying: can't create folder check if parent folder is writeable.

BUT: if I put the same code into the wp-blog-header.php file uploading and building new folders within the upload folder works.

I thought using `DEFINE`(in my case) means that I just save a string value to a constant and where ever I use the constant the value is the same. But **how can it be that there is a difference when defining a constant in wp-config.php or wp-blog-header.php?** (which is inside the subfolder `wordpress` .

For my changes in wp-blog-header.php would disappear after the next Wordpress update I obviously can't solve it that way.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Can you try an absolute path instead of the relative one?

Comment: Shouldn't it just be 'content/uploads' ? Since wp-config.php is within the root.

Comment: @kero the path has to be relative because wordpress puts abspath before that

Comment: @BasvanDijk because wordpress works inside the subfolder the abspath points to the subfolder and this way you have to go up one folder-level first

Comment: @Luckyfella Since plugins and themes are in there as well, can't you just set `WP_CONTENT_DIR`?

Comment: @kero that was a good hint! I already had that constant defined and after removing the definition of UPLOADS constant it works! Thank you! But I still wonder why it works with the constant when defining in wp-blog-header.php ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>(Converting my comment to an answer.)</sub>

Since you store themes and plugins in that folder as well, try setting the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` constant instead. (Always prefer absolute paths when possible.)

As to your specific case, why it worked in one file but not in another - this will probably involve more debugging, checking where exactly WP uses which constant, etc. If setting `WP_CONTENT_DIR` solves your problem, remove `UPLOADS` and work with it.